# Running multiple OLS regressions with matrix algebra in R

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, least-squares

I am having trouble running multiple regressions in R. I have a matrix of returns, which have to be regressed against a vector. To be clear, I have a matrix of 1794 assets, which each, individually, need to be regressed against the SPX. I then need to roll these regressions through time, so I am trying to do this with matrix algebra to get the best speed possible.

I have code like the following:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(fundReturns) - 59)){
  tempMatrix <- fundReturns[i:(i+59),]
  tempSPX <- spxReturns[i:(i+59)]
  theSubset <- sapply(tempMatrix, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) == 0
  tempMatrix <- tempMatrix[,theSubset]
  theBeta <- solve(crossprod(tempMatrix), crossprod(tempMatrix, tempSPX))
  theBetas[index(fundReturns)[(i + 59)], colnames(theBeta)] = theBeta
}
```

This breaks on the first iteration, at the 'theBeta <- ...' line. I am getting the following error:

```
Error in solve.default(t(tempMatrix) %*% tempMatrix) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[273,273] = 0
```

I assume this means I have some singular matrix somewhere, which does not make sense to me. (If someone could explain what this error means exactly, that would be worth bonus points.) I do not see where the error could be coming from, and to boot, I attempted to check with the following code:

```
for (i in 1:1794){
  tempMatrix2 <- tempMatrix[,i]
  theBeta <- solve(t(tempMatrix2) %*% tempMatrix2) %*% (t(tempMatrix2) %*% tempSPX)
}
```

This code runs fine, and produces a beta for each individual column. I assume there is something I am missing in my code, or have some calculation backwards, but I cannot find it. Please SO gods, help me.

If it helps, here is the following:

```
> dim(tempSPX)
[1] 60  1
> dim(tempMatrix)
[1]   60 1794
```

Comment: `BetaMatrix <- apply(tempMatrix, 2, function(x) coef(lm(tempSPX ~ x)))` (instead of the loop `for (i in 1:1794) ...`)

Comment: The loop for (i in 1:1794) was simply thrown together to demonstrate that the matrix should work, and not error out. Is lm() not much slower than the matrix algebra? And is there no way to do this without looping with apply? This seems like it would be horribly slow, relatively.

Comment: The accuracy of lm() is better than your matrix algebra. Your inverting is terrible slow: there you should use `solve(A, b)`. For the matrix multiplications use `crossprod()`. For testing the speed you can do benchmarks (e.g. with the package `microbenchmark`)

Comment: I edited the above. Thanks for the speed tip. However, I still get the same error: Error in solve.default(crossprod(tempMatrix), crossprod(tempMatrix, tempSPX)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[273,273] = 0

Comment: And accuracy isn't THAT important. If I could get 3-4 digits, I am fine.